# Update post meta using pending_to_publish hook

Tags: hooks, post-meta

Below is my code for updating post meta.

```
function changePostExpireDatetime( $post ){
  $featurePlanID = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post_price_plan_id', true );

  remove_action('pending_to_publish', 'changePostExpireDatetime', 10, 1);
  $plan_price = get_post_meta($featurePlanID, 'plan_price', true);
  update_post_meta($post->ID, 'post_plan_price', $plan_price );

  update_post_meta($post->ID, 'featured_post', "1" );
  add_action('pending_to_publish', 'changePostExpireDatetime', 10, 1);
}
add_action('pending_to_publish', 'changePostExpireDatetime', 10, 1);
```

Function is called but meta is was not updated. How can I update post meta in that hook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to make use of the [`transition_post_status`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions) hook as it gives you so much control over what you need to do. Be sure to check out the link for all available status options. What I specially like that the `$post` object is also passed to the hook, so you can target a specific post type as well for one.

You can try something like the following: (*Just be sure to update the values to your own, I just used mine as example*)

```
 add_action(  'transition_post_status',  function ( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) 
{
    // Check if we are transitioning from pending to publish
    if ( $old_status == 'pending'  &&  $new_status == 'publish' ) {
        // Check whether or not the meta_key exists already with our value
        if ( ! add_post_meta( $post->ID, 'post_views_count', 50, true ) ) { 
           update_post_meta ( $post->ID, 'post_views_count', 50 );
        }
    }
}, 10, 3 );
```

Comment: My pleasure, glad it worked out for you. Enjoy ;-)